# Xamarin iOS Reading Step Counts from HealthKit

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, healthkit

I am trying to read the stepcount from 365 days back in time from the user and then upload this to a server. But I'm currently stuck at extracting the data, I get the permission from the iOS healthkit correctly, but the return type of my data is just get "[0:] HealthKit.HKSample[]"

```
public void GetSteps()
{        
    var healthKitStore = new HKHealthStore();
    var stepRateType = HKQuantityType.Create(HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.StepCount);
    var sort = new NSSortDescriptor(HKSample.SortIdentifierStartDate, true);
    var q = new HKSampleQuery(stepRateType, HKQuery.GetPredicateForSamples(NSDate.Now.AddSeconds(TimeSpan.FromDays(-365).TotalSeconds), NSDate.Now.AddSeconds(TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalSeconds), HKQueryOptions.None), 0, new NSSortDescriptor[] { },
        new HKSampleQueryResultsHandler((HKSampleQuery query2,HKSample[] results, NSError error2) =>
        {
            var query = results; //property created within the model to expose later.
            Debug.WriteLine(query);
            Debug.WriteLine(results);
        }));
    healthKitStore.ExecuteQuery(q); 
}
```

Comment: detail documentation and demo here : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_healthkit/

Comment: I have read that guide, but I could not find anything helpful to fix the data problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know why you are getting "[0:] HealthKit.HKSample[]", you are trying to Debug.WriteLine an array of objects. The results variable is an array. Loop through the array instead and extract out the "Quantity", "StartDate", and "EndDate" among other fields that are available:

```
foreach (var item in results)
{
    var sample = (HKQuantitySample) item;
    var hkUnit = HKUnit.Count;
    var quantity = sample.Quantity.GetDoubleValue(hkUnit);
    var startDateTime = sample.StartDate.ToDateTime().ToLocalTime();
    var endDateTime = sample.EndDate.ToDateTime().ToLocalTime();
    Debug.WriteLine(quantity);
    Debug.WriteLine(startDateTime);
    Debug.WriteLine(endDateTime);
}
```